# Execute SQL statement starting with "WITH" keyword in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

The following query works fine in SQL Server:

```
with tt AS
(
select schema_name(fk_tab.schema_id) + '.' + fk_tab.name as foreign_table,
'>-' as rel,
schema_name(pk_tab.schema_id) + '.' + pk_tab.name as primary_table,
fk_cols.constraint_column_id as no,
fk_col.name as fk_column_name,
' = ' as [join],
pk_col.name as pk_column_name,
fk.name as fk_constraint_name
from sys.foreign_keys fk
inner join sys.tables fk_tab
on fk_tab.object_id = fk.parent_object_id
inner join sys.tables pk_tab
on pk_tab.object_id = fk.referenced_object_id
inner join sys.foreign_key_columns fk_cols
on fk_cols.constraint_object_id = fk.object_id
inner join sys.columns fk_col
on fk_col.column_id = fk_cols.parent_column_id
and fk_col.object_id = fk_tab.object_id
inner join sys.columns pk_col
on pk_col.column_id = fk_cols.referenced_column_id
and pk_col.object_id = pk_tab.object_id
)
 select tt.foreign_table, tt.primary_table, tt.fk_constraint_name
 ,(
SELECT SUBSTRING(
(
SELECT ',' + t.fk_column_name
FROM tt as t
WHERE tt.fk_constraint_name = t.fk_constraint_name FOR XML PATH('')), 2, 200000)
) AS fk_constraint_name
,(
SELECT SUBSTRING(
(
SELECT ',' + t.pk_column_name
FROM tt as t
WHERE tt.fk_constraint_name = t.fk_constraint_name FOR XML PATH('')), 2, 200000)
) AS pk_column_name
from tt
group by tt.foreign_table, tt.primary_table, tt.fk_constraint_name
```

it returns a table cotainig all foreign keys in my DB.

I am now trying to execute it in a Spark script on Databricks.
This is what I've done.

```
// ch contains my query
val df=spark.sql(ch)
```

But I get this error:

```
ParseException: 
no viable alternative at input 'with tt AS\n(\nselect schema_name(fk_tab.schema_id) + '.' + fk_tab.name as foreign_table,\n'>-' as rel,\nschema_name(pk_tab.schema_id) + '.' + pk_tab.name as primary_table,\nfk_cols.constraint_column_id as no,\nfk_col.name as fk_column_name,\n' = ' as
```

Is it not possible to execute such queries with spark sql ?
If not, how can I do that please ?

Comment: Divide and conquer: Start with a bare minimum working CTE and then start building it up in stages until you encounter your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I just figured it out, for such requests, createStatement should be used:

```
import java.sql._
val connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl)
val stmt1 = connection.createStatement 
val rs: ResultSet = stmt1.executeQuery(ch)

while (rs.next) {
  println(rs.getString("col1"))
  // ...
}
```